# Android GridView With Image is Too Slow when using universalimageloader

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

I am using **universalimageloader** in my project to Show many images
When I try to show images it is too Slow, After commented Line Of Display Images it shows Rows as well and not Slow
the Code I tried is :

```
public class GridAdapterMa extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<JobItem> objects = new ArrayList<JobItem>();
    int size = 0;
    private String TAG = GridAdapterMa.class.getSimpleName();
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    DisplayImageOptions options;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
    public GridAdapterMa(ArrayList<JobItem> objects) {
        size = objects.size();
        this.objects.addAll(objects);
        ExceptionHelpers.dLog(TAG, "Constructor");
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.thumb_square)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.thumb_square)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.thumb_square)
                // .cacheInMemory(false)
                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                // .delayBeforeLoading(100)
                .considerExifParams(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())
                /*.preProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                    @Override
                    public Bitmap process(Bitmap bitmap) {
                        int w = (int) (UIHelpers.width * 0.50);
                        float r = ((float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) bitmap.getWidth());
                        int h = (int) (w * r);
                        ExceptionHelpers.dLog(TAG, "Adapter Width : " + w + " Height : " + h + " R : " + r);
                        ExceptionHelpers.dLog(TAG, "Adapter Width : " + bitmap.getWidth() + " Height : " + bitmap.getHeight());
                        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, false);
                    }
                })*/
                .build();
        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(App.context)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .memoryCacheSize(41943040)
                .discCacheSize(104857600)
                .threadPoolSize(10)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return size;
    }
    @Override
    public JobItem getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        try {
            if(convertView==null){
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) App.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                if(UIHelpers.screen_density >= 4){
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.grid_ma_xl, null);
                }else{
                    convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.grid_ma_m, null);
                }

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.img =(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_image_gv_ma);
                holder.imgVip = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_vip_gv_ma);
                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_gv_item);
                holder.txtCat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cat_gv_item);
                holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc_gv_item);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(App.context.getAssets(), "b_yekan.ttf");
            Typeface tf1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(App.context.getAssets(), "b_mitra.ttf");
            holder.txtTitle.setTypeface(tf1);
            holder.txtCat.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.txtDesc.setTypeface(tf);
            holder.txtTitle.setTextSize(UIHelpers.titleFont);
            holder.txtCat.setTextSize(UIHelpers.descFont);
            holder.txtDesc.setTextSize(UIHelpers.descFont);
            if(objects.get(position).getjVip()==1) {
                holder.imgVip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (objects.get(position).getjVip()==0) {
                holder.imgVip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            String imgURL = "";
            imgURL = imgURL + objects.get(position).getjImage();
            // ExceptionHelpers.dLog(TAG, "imgURL : '" + imgURL + "'");
            /*if(imgURL.equals("http://www.yazdjobs.com/null") ||
                    imgURL.equals("http://www.yazdjobs.com/") ||
                    imgURL.equals("http://yazdjobs.com/null") ||
                    imgURL.equals("http://yazdjobs.com/")){
                imgURL = "http://www.yazdjobs.com/wp-content/themes/yazdjobs/images/no-image.png";
            }*/
            // ExceptionHelpers.dLog(TAG, "imgURL : '" + imgURL + "'");
            // ExceptionHelpers.dLog(TAG, "Position : "+position+" / "+objects.size());
            // Show Images
            // imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(App.context));

            imageLoader.init(config);
            ImageAware imageAware = new ImageViewAware(holder.img, false);
            imageLoader.displayImage(imgURL, imageAware, options);

            /*Picasso.with(App.context)
                    .load(imgURL)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.thumb_square)
                    .error(R.drawable.thumb_square)
                    .into(holder.img);*/
            holder.txtTitle.setText(objects.get(position).getjTitle());
            holder.txtCat.setText(objects.get(position).getjCatName());
            if(UIHelpers.screen_density >= 4){
                holder.txtDesc.setText(objects.get(position).getjDescLimit());
            }else{
                holder.txtDesc.setText(objects.get(position).getjDesc());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ExceptionHelpers.catchMessage(e);
            ExceptionHelpers.eLog(TAG, "Error in Grid Adapter >> " + e, e);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView img;
        private ImageView imgVip;
        private TextView txtTitle;
        private TextView txtCat;
        private TextView txtDesc;
    }
}
```

I Even Tried ImageLoaderConfiguration But Not works To Me.
How To Fix It

Comment: Try removing: .delayBeforeLoading(100) and changing .cacheInMemory(true) to load already loaded image,  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 is more efficient

Comment: before i was using UIL but now i was using picasso its very good at Cache levels try picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/  , refer this link as well https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/bfAFC5YZ3mq

Comment: @subhash Does not works to me.

Comment: @SatishPathuri Picasso Library does not works